# What is the air pressure in a bubble of air trapped in an upturned beaker?

Tags: pressure, air

If I trap some air in an upturned beaker like this:

[image: upturned beaker]

What will be the air pressure inside the beaker?

If I introduce say 10cm<sup>3</sup> at atmospheric pressure via a pipe, I guess it will take up a smaller volume once in the beaker?

I am not too fussed about the tiny details like the vapour pressure of the water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start off with beaker filled with water and completely submersed in the bath, with the beaker upside down (as in your schematic). Now, via some conduit, you introduce 10 ml of air into the beaker. Then move the beaker upwards until the water levels inside and outside of the beaker coincide exactly. The pressure of the air inside the beaker is now exactly the same as a the pressure of the air outside of the beaker, say $p_0 = 1 atm$.

But as you move the beaker upwards to the position shown in your schematic, the column of water between the upper level in your beaker and the level in your bath actually reduces pressure of the air inside the beaker by an amount $\Delta p_h$.

$\Delta p_h$ is the hydrostatic pressure of the water column inside the beaker and is given by:

$\Delta p_h = \rho gh$ with $\rho$ the density of the liquid, $g = 9.8 ms^{-2}$ and $h$ the difference in water level inside and outside the beaker.

The actual air pressure in the beaker is now:

$p= p_0 - \Delta p_h$

Plug in the numbers (using correct units) and see that for a few cm of column $\Delta p_h$ is very small (but easily measurable).

Comment: Brilliant thank you.

Then I can find out the pressure of the specific gas in the space by subtracting the partial vapour pressure of water.

I am doing this as I am designing a chemistry practical for my students to measure the molar mass of a gas from a gas canister.

obviously a reasonably accurate measurement of the pressure exerted by the gas needs to be known!

Answer (score 0):

The pressure in the water at a certain level ($z$-coordinate) is everywhere the same. This implies that the pressure at the water surface outside the beaker, i.e. the atmospheric pressure $p_0$ has to be equal to the sum of the pressure created by the water column $\rho g h$ and the air pressure in the beaker $p_b$. $\rho$ is the density of the water, $g$ the acceleration due to gravitation and $h$ the height of the water level in the beaker. In other words $$p_b = p_0 - \rho gh$$

Comment: Thank you very much.
Ended up with the same ultimate answer as the previous comment.